# How to access Vuex store from nuxt router module's router.js file?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vue-router

- I am using [`nuxt-community/router-module`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module)
- It requires you to create a `router.js` file where you can add global routing configuration
- How do I access the store from that file?

Comment: have you tried just importing store `import store from '@/store'`?

Comment: @SergeyMitrichev TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, just added import store from '@/store' inside the router.js file and tried accessing a state variable inside beforeEach

Comment: import store from '@/store'
import store from './store' nothing works second one has this error No default export found in imported module "./store"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could access the store through the root context, which Nuxt provides in [`window.$nuxt`](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/context-helpers/#accessing-the-root-instance) outside Vue components:

```js
// router.js
import Router from 'vue-router'

export function createRouter(ssrContext, createDefaultRouter, routerOptions) {
  const options = routerOptions ? routerOptions : createDefaultRouter(ssrContext).options

  const router = new Router({
    ...options
  })

  if (process.client) {
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      // Since `beforeEach` is invoked before `window.$nuxt` is
      // initialized, use `setTimeout` without a timeout to wait
      // until the next macro tick.
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.$nuxt.$store.dispatch('myAction')
      })

      next()
    })
  }

  return router
}
```

If the only reason for using `@nuxtjs/router` module were to add a `beforeEach` router hook, you could actually accomplish that with a [Nuxt plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins) instead:

```js
// plugins/router.js
export default ({ app, store }) => {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('myAction')
    next()
  })
}

// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    '~plugins/router.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: window.$nuxt won't be available server side